CROSS APPLY OPENJSON for 2D-data
I have data from a sensor with 3 channels, measured every 10 minutes - the data is given as JSON in a table in one column.
For each timestamp ts there are 3 YValues as an array (Intensity-Values) with corresponding XValues (XAxis_nm) given as an array as well
JSON - Example for one column entry (lets say column name is colJsonText:
{"ts": "2024-04-17T10:10:00", "Intensities": [101, 102, 103], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}
Now I want to query the JSON data with the following result:
desired result
I have tried the following query ( I have added example data for 2 rows of colJson directly into the query so that it is easy to reproduce:
SELECT ts, Intensity, XAxis_nm FROM OPENJSON('[{"ts": "2024-04-17T10:10:00", "Intensities": [101, 102, 103], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}, {"ts": "2024-04-17T10:20:00", "Intensities": [201, 202, 203], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}]') WITH (ts nvarchar(32), Intensities NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, XAxis_nm NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) AS a CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (a.Intensities) WITH (Intensity INT '$')

The result looks like:
result of query
How can I get only the corresponding XAxis-Value instead of the entire XAxis_nm for each row like shown in the picture 'desired result' ?
SOLUTION (based on the answer from 'Power Mouse'):

    DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null, rawjson nvarchar(2000) NULL)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('[
{"Sensor": "S01", "ts": "2024-04-17T10:10:00", "Intensities": [101, 102, 103], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430], "Context": ["410nm", "420nm", "430nm"]}
, {"Sensor": "S01", "ts": "2024-04-17T10:20:00", "Intensities": [201, 202, 203], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430], "Context": ["410nm", "420nm", "430nm"]}
, {"Sensor": "S01", "ts": "2024-04-17T10:30:00", "Intensities": [210, 102, 203], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430], "Context": ["410nm", "420nm", "430nm"]}
, {"Sensor": "S02", "ts": "2024-04-17T10:30:00", "Intensities": [210, 1020, 203], "XAxis_nm": [420, 410, 430], "Context": ["410nm", "420nm", "430nm"]}
]')

select 
    c.ts,
    c.X,
    Intensity = JSON_VALUE(c.json, '$['+ CAST(c.RowNum-1 as varchar(5)) +']'),
    c.SensorName
    , Context = JSON_VALUE(c.json1, '$['+ CAST(c.RowNum-1 as varchar(5)) +']')
from (
    SELECT 
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Sensor, ts, XAxis_nm ORDER BY ts ASC),
        ts = CAST(ts as DateTime), 
        X = Cast(XValue as int), 
        SensorName = Sensor,
        Intensities as json
        , Context as json1
    FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.rawjson) WITH (
                ts nvarchar(32), 
                Sensor nvarchar(32), 
                XAxis_nm nvarchar(max) as JSON
                , Intensities NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
                , Context NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
                )
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (XAxis_nm) WITH (XValue INT '$')
    --outer APPLY OPENJSON (XAxis_nm) WITH (XAxis INT '$')
) c 



i am not clear how you want to see so i created example with set of 3

DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null, rawjson nvarchar(2000) NULL)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('[{"ts": "2024-04-17T10:10:00", "Intensities": [101, 102, 103], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}, {"ts": "2024-04-17T10:20:00", "Intensities": [201, 202, 203], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}]')

SELECT 
    ts
    ,JSON_VALUE(XAxis_nm, '$[0]') AS XAxis1
    ,JSON_VALUE(Intensities, '$[0]') AS Intensity1

    ,JSON_VALUE(XAxis_nm, '$[1]') AS XAxis2
    ,JSON_VALUE(Intensities, '$[1]') AS Intensity2

    ,JSON_VALUE(XAxis_nm, '$[2]') AS XAxis3
    ,JSON_VALUE(Intensities, '$[2]') AS Intensity3
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.rawjson) WITH (
            ts nvarchar(32), 
            Intensities NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, 
            XAxis_nm nvarchar(max) as json)
--CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Intensities) WITH (Intensity INT '$')
--outer APPLY OPENJSON (XAxis_nm) WITH (XAxis INT '$')




result would be:



ts
XAxis1
Intensity1
XAxis2
Intensity2
XAxis3
Intensity3




2024-04-17T10:10:00
410
101
420
102
430
103


2024-04-17T10:20:00
410
201
420
202
430
203



UPDATE
it took me time to understand what you try to achieve. i guess this is what are you looking for:

DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) not null, rawjson nvarchar(2000) NULL)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('[{"ts": "2024-04-17T10:10:00", "Intensities": [101, 102, 103], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}, {"ts": "2024-04-17T10:20:00", "Intensities": [201, 202, 203], "XAxis_nm": [410, 420, 430]}]')

select 
    c.ts,
    c.inten,
    XAxis1 = JSON_VALUE(c.json, '$['+ CAST(c.RowNum-1 as varchar(5)) +']')
from (
    SELECT 
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Intensities ORDER BY Intensity ASC),
        ts = CAST(ts as DateTime), 
        inten = Cast(Intensity as int), 
        XAxis_nm as json
    FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.rawjson) WITH (
                ts nvarchar(32), 
                Intensities NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, 
                XAxis_nm nvarchar(max) as JSON)
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Intensities) WITH (Intensity INT '$')
    --outer APPLY OPENJSON (XAxis_nm) WITH (XAxis INT '$')
) c 


result


Absolutly amazing - thank you so much!   The part after 'UPDATE' was exactly what I was looking for. Especially the trick with the ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY was the part I was missing.
